# How can I pass data to the MATLAB oncleanup function?

Tags: matlab, exception

I have a compiled matlab program that automatically tunes machine parameters. At the end of a tuning cycle I need to reistate some original settings. Sometime unexpected errors occur and sometimes the user can see that tuning algorithm is not working properly so should be terminated (with control-C).

If a predictable error occurs, I can reinstate parameters with a try catch block. However, if an unexpected error occurs or the user invokes control-C, the program exits without passing though the catch clause and the machine is left in an undefined state.

I know I can register a cleanup function that will run as my working functions finish, either normally, via an predictable or unpredictable error, or control-C event. Ideally, the the clean up function would do nothing and pass control to the top level to clean up if a predictable error occurs. If a control-C event or an unpredictable error occurs, clean up function should warn the user that the program failed so they clean up manually.

To do this, I need to make the fact of a predicted or not-predicted termination (i.e. control-C) known to the clean up function at run time. I know that the cleanup function takes a copy of parameter values when it is registered, and that these cannot be changed at run time, so passing in a parameter cannot work. What I believe should work is nesting the cleanup function within my working function so local variables in the enclosing function are available to the clean up function. This however does not work.

My question is: can anyone see a way to make just a single boolean available to a clean function so it can select between normal and abnormal clean up?

Here is some contrived example code that I believe should work.

```
function do_tuning
  % Set this false to cause a warning messages for control-C or MATLAB coding errors.
  normalTermination = false;
  oc = onCleanup(@() my_clean_up());
  tuningError = tuning_function()   
  if tuningError
    % Set this true to suppress the warning message if a predictable error occurs.
    normalTermination = true;
    error('tuningError')
  end
  % Set this true to suppress the warning message if the function runs to completion.
  normalTermination = true;

  function my_clean_up
    if ~normalTermination
      disp('Warning: clean up failed. Please clean up manually');
    end
  end
end
```

Running real code following this pattern causes the error:

```
Undefined function or variable "normalTermination".
```

Comment: It is not elegant, but have you considered a [`global`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/global.html) variable?

Comment: @RTL, Global seems to work. If you make your comment an answer, the kudos is yours.

Comment: I think the answer from @RTL (using a `global`) is probably the only way I can think of to solve the question as asked. But (no disrespect) it's a really dirty solution - if a user (or any other MATLAB script) decided to stupidly change the global `normalTermination` at the wrong time, your machine would still be left in an undefined state. It's not really how `onCleanup` is intended to be used - it would be better practice to do *all* cleanup within `myCleanup`, rather than half somewhere else, and then have to determine within `myCleanup` if it's been done or not.

Comment: @Sam Roberts I agree a global is really not the best solution to this problem ..but was the only solution to the question I could think of (hence calling it "not elegant").

Comment: @Sam Roberts, your observation is a good one and I will reconsider my options. My problem is that the settings to be reinstated belong to the whole machine, whereas a number of similar movements are tuned, one by one, and any one can fail. I am in this mess because MATLAB handles control-C (and coding errors) differently to thrown errors. I haven't found a good way to do something globally to react to an error or control-C at the movement level. If you have any suggestions, I am listening. (Or if you think I should rewrite this as a new question, please let me know.)

Comment: @NigelDavies {Comment 1 of 2} Sure. Think of it like this - an `onCleanup` object is just an object with a destructor (i.e. a `delete` method) set to whatever you want. But you can give any class this capability by implementing its `delete` method, not just by using `onCleanup`. So I would write a class (called something like `MachineConnection`) that represents a connection to your machine (this would be a good use of a Singleton class pattern). `do_tuning` would create a `MachineConnection` object, and do whatever it needed to with it.

Comment: @NigelDavies {Comment 2 of 2} The `MachineConnection` class would have a destructor (`delete` method) that did whatever cleanup was necessary when then connection to the machine is closed - this would then execute when the object goes out of scope at the end of `do_tuning`, however it finished (either normally, by an error, or with Ctrl-C). If you're not familiar with OO programming in MATLAB, none of the above is likely to make sense to you - but if not, then I think it might be worth your while to look into it. (I'm also *cough* available for consulting... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onCleanup` object calls the function from outside the workspace of the `do_tuning` function so using a nested function will not help...
Infact the documetation states:

> [Your cleanup routine should never rely on variables that are defined outside of that routine](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/cleaning-up-when-the-function-completes.html)

[edit - based on comments] A better solution would be to change the problem and have **all** cleaning up done within the my_clean_up function, which may require it to determine if what needs doing (or to have generic behaviour which can always be applied)

If we disregard this warning and solve the question...

Passing varables between workspaces is easiest with [`global`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/global.html) variables so for the example code above. 
Firstly define the variable as global **before** initially setting it to false (otherwise the variable may be overwritten)

```
function do_tuning
    %# snip
    global normalTermination
    normalTermination = false;
    %# snip
```

Secondly define the variable as global in the my_clean_up callback function **before** using it to retrieve the value

```
function my_clean_up
    global normalTermination
    if ~normalTermination
    %# snip
```

**Warning** as ever with global variables this is susceptible to the value of the global variable being edited elsewhere at the wrong time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modification of my example that behaves as I want, using the global suggested by @RTL.

```
function do_tuning

  global normalTermination;

  % Set this false to cause a warning messages for control-C or MATLAB coding errors.
  normalTermination = false;
  oc = onCleanup(@() my_clean_up());
  tuningError = tuning_function()   
  if tuningError
    % Set this true to suppress the warning message if a predictable error occurs.
    normalTermination = true;
    error('tuningError')
  end
  % Set this true to suppress the warning message if the function runs to completion.
  normalTermination = true;

  function my_clean_up
    if ~normalTermination
      disp('Warning: clean up failed. Please clean up manually');
    else
      disp('Normal termination, you can relax.');
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution can be achieved by modifying the onCleanup code. You could easily add a property or method to cancel the normal behaviour. Example:

```
classdef onCleanupCancel < handle

    properties
        active = true;
    end

    properties(SetAccess = 'private', GetAccess = 'public', Transient)
        task = @nop;
    end

    methods
        function h = onCleanupCancel(functionHandle)
            h.task = functionHandle;
        end

        function delete(h)
            if h.active
                h.task();
            end
        end
    end
end
function nop
end
```

At the last line of your function set the active of the onCleanupCancel object to false...

Comment: I think I understand your suggestion, but I am not sure how to apply it in context. Do you feel inclined to modify my trivial example show show when your class is created and what you use when you call onCleanup()?