# Do I have to redefine my matlab cleanup object when input arguments change?

Tags: matlab, code-cleanup

I have a cleanup function that relies on a couple of arguments that alter the behavior of the cleanup routine:

```
function MainFunction()
x=1;
y=1;
cleanupObj = onCleanup(@()cleanupFun(x,y));
end
function cleanupFun(x,y)
    if(x)
        %do something
    end
    if(y)
        %do another thing
    end
end
```

Now, in my broader use case, x and y will be changing many times throughout the life of MainFunction.  Do I have to redefine my cleanupObj everytime x or y changes? For my case this would be quite ugly.
Another idea I've thought of is making use of the fact that x and y are changed by subfunctions.  Is it possible to pass the cleanup object handle to these subfunctions so that I can redefine the cleanup object handle from within the subfunction, rather than redefining it after each call to the sub function?

Comment: the following thread seems to answer my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265495/how-can-i-pass-data-to-the-matlab-oncleanup-function